# Selecionar apenas a primeira linha de cada usuario

Tags: php, sql

Tenho uma tabela onde movimento saldo (depósitos e saque), porem em um campo do site preciso trazer apenas o saldo do primeiro deposito.

Seria algo assim:

```
select saldo from historico where id = :id and (algum filtro)
```

Já tentei com `top 1`, e `limit 0,01` mas dava erro.

Comment: Qual é o servidor de banco de dados? MySQL, Oracle, ...

Comment: Para recuperar os dados do primeiro depósito pegue o registro com a data mais antiga. Não confie na ordem com que o SGBD recupera os registros pois, dependendo do SGBD, não necessariamente será na mesma ordem com que foram gravados.

Comment: Seria mysql o banco de dados

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa tarde.

A query que colocou é um pouco confusa, porque não é perceptível se a coluna "id" se refere ao identificador único de um registo nessa tabela ou se é o id de um utilizador. No entanto, partindo do princípio que é o id de um utilizador, então pode usar a seguinte query:

```
Select saldo From historico Where id = :id Limit 1
```

Isto devolde um único registo da tabela (o primeiro do resultado obtido pela primeira parte da query). Se quiser, pode adicionar um parâmetro de ordenação, com recurso a um "Order By  ASC" (ordenação ascendente) ou "Order By  DESC" (ordenação descendente).

Espero ter ajudado.